# Loop of composite type as stored procedure input PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, types, plpgsql

I am creating a stored procedure by passing a type and do a loop inside the procedure so that I can insert each info type

This is my type

```
 create type leketo as(id integer, name text);
```

Function that inserts rows into my type

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getLeketo()
  RETURNS SETOF leketo AS
$BODY$
declare
l leketo;
begin

l.id := 1;
l.name := 'One';
return next l;

l.id := 2;
l.name := 'Two';
return next l;


l.id := 3;
l.name := 'Three';
return next l;


l.id := 4;
l.name := 'Four';
return next l;

l.id := 5;
l.name := 'Five';
return next l;

end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Running the function returns this to me

```
select * from getLeketo()

1  One 
2  Two 
3  Three 
4  Four 
5  Five
```

In this procedure we will go through all the rows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loopLeketo(pl leketo)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
l leketo;
begin

 for l in (select * from pl) loop
  raise notice '----------------------------------------';
  raise notice 'id=%, name=%', l.id, l.name;
 end loop;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

If I try this I get the following message

```
DO $$
declare
l leketo;
begin
select * from getLeketo() into l;
PERFORM loopLeketo(l);
end$$;
```

**ERROR:  relation "pl" does not exist**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error message because a parameter (in your case `pl`) cannot occur in the `FROM` clause of a query, so PostgreSQL will interpret `pl` as a table name.

The deeper problem is that you try to assign a set of values to a single variable, which will not work. Your `SELECT ... INTO` statement will only store the first result in the variable `l`.

You don't tell us what you really want to achieve, but I can think of two approaches for the problem you show:

1. Handle the query results one by one. PL/pgSQL code would look like that:

   ```
   DEFINE
      l leketo;
   BEGIN
      FOR l IN SELECT * FROM getleketo() LOOP
         RAISE NOTICE 'id=%, name=%', l.id, l.name;
      END LOOP;
   END;
   ```
2. Define `getleketo()` not as `RETURNS SETOF leketo`, but as `RETURNS refcursor` and have it return a cursor for the results. Then you can assign the whole query result to a variable of type `refcursor` and use this as an argument to the `loopleketo` function.

   See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) for details.